# Upload data with image from Android to MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

So I am new with android studio and php and I am building a registration form and I have a problem with signup  ,since I need to upload info with image to MySQL database ,I am using localhost (phpmyadmin)
This is my database image in the link ,I deleted the code with bold code below to insert other data except image ,since the main problem come from there .
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Glx.png
when I click the signup button the activity crash and this error occur :

```
2021-05-17 22:13:03.458 6529-7060/com.example.lebanesecuisine E/lebanesecuisin: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
2021-05-17 22:13:03.460 6529-7060/com.example.lebanesecuisine E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-18
```

**This is my PHP Code :**

```
    <?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','loginregister');

 $full_name = $_POST['fullname'];
 $user_name =  $_POST['username'];
 $email_user =  $_POST['email'];
 $password_user = $_POST['password'];
***$image = $_POST['imageurl'];***
 
 $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email_user'";
 
 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$CheckSQL));
 
 if(isset($check)){
   
 echo 'Email Already Exist';

 }
**else{ 
  if($_FILES['upload']){
    $on=$_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $sn=$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $dn="images/".$on;
    move_uploaded_file($sn,$dn);
  }**
 
   **$sql ="SELECT `id` FROM `users` ORDER BY id ASC";
 
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
$id = 0;
 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 $id = $row['id'];
 }
 
 $p = ".images/$id.jpg";
 
 $path = "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.phproute=/sql&server=1&db=loginregister&table=users&pos=0/$p";**
 
  
$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO users(fullname,username,email,pass,**pic**) values('$full_name','$user_name','$email_user','$password_user',**'$path'**)";
 if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))
{
   **file_put_contents($p,base64_decode($image));**
 echo 'Registration Successfully';
}
else
{
 echo 'Something went wrong';
 }
  }

  
 }

 echo 'OK';
?>
```

**signup.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Signup">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0"
        />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33"
        />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.44"
        />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55"
        />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="482dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.77" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90"
        />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Signup"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Signup_Image"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email Address
"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/eFullname"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/UserName"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Signupbtn"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="53sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"
        app:cornerRadius="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Already own an account?"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginlink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bg"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and last this is my **Signup.java**

```
    public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG =Signup.class.getSimpleName();
    public EditText editTextfullname,editTextusername,editTextpassword,editTextemail;
  public  String str_fullname,str_username,str_password,str_email,encoded_string, image_name,path;
  private String server_url = "http://192.168.2.209/Loginregister/signup.php";
  //  public static final String TAG = "MY MESSAGE";
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Uri filePath;
   public TextView textViewlogin;
  public Button signupbtn;
 public ProgressBar progressBar;
ImageView signupimage;
//byte[] byteArray ;
public static final String PRODUCT_PHOTO = "photo";
    public static Bitmap product_image;
 private static final int IMAGE_PICKUP_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
 RequestQueue queue;
    public static Bitmap image;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
       editTextfullname=findViewById(R.id.eFullname);
        editTextusername=findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        editTextpassword=findViewById(R.id.Password);
        editTextemail=findViewById(R.id.eEmailAddress);
        textViewlogin = findViewById(R.id.loginlink);
        signupbtn = findViewById(R.id.Signupbtn);
        signupimage=findViewById(R.id.Signup_Image);
        progressBar =findViewById(R.id.progress);
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);




        signupimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //---------set the image to bitmap



                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
//permission not granted,request it
                        String [] permission ={Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        //show popup for run time permission
                        requestPermissions(permission,PERMISSION_CODE);

               /* Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);*/
                    }
                    else {
//permission already granted
                        pickImageFromGallery();
                    }
                }
                else {
//Bruhh
                    pickImageFromGallery();
                }





            }
        });


        signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                userRegister();
            }
        });






        textViewlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    private void userRegister() {
        if (editTextfullname.getText().toString().equals("") || editTextusername.getText().toString().equals("") || editTextpassword.getText().toString().equals("") || editTextemail.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Please Fill out All fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                    uploadFile(path);
                }
            }).start();
            str_fullname = editTextfullname.getText().toString().trim();
            str_username = editTextusername.getText().toString().trim();
            str_password = editTextpassword.getText().toString().trim();
            str_email = editTextemail.getText().toString().trim();
           // path = getPath(filePath);
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, response -> {
                //  dialog.dismiss();
                if (response.contains("Registration Successfully")) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Navigation.class));
                    finish();

                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, error.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            }) {
                @Nullable
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    //NEW CODE
                    //   String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
                    //NEW CODE
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                 //   String imgdata =getStringImage(bitmap);
                 //   params.put("pic",imgdata);
                    params.put("fullname", str_fullname);
                    params.put("username", str_username);
                    params.put("password", str_password);
                    params.put("email", str_email);
                    params.put("key", "GFHregister");


                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(request);
        }
    }

    public int uploadFile( final  String  path) {
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(path);


        String[] parts = path.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

        if (!selectedFile.isFile()){


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Source File Doesn't Exist: " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }else{
            try{
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL(server_url);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
                connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
                connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("upload",path);

                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\";filename=\""
                        + path + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

                //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                while (bytesRead > 0){
                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });
                }

                //closing the input and output streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return serverResponseCode;
    }


    private void pickImageFromGallery() {
      /*  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(i,IMAGE_PICKUP_CODE);*/
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_PICKUP_CODE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMISSION_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    pickImageFromGallery();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Persmission is not granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      /*  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICKUP_CODE) {
            signupimage.setImageURI(data.getData());*/
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKUP_CODE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePath);
                bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                signupimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }  
    }
}
```